# NULL is displaying as '\N' when write the result of Hive query in text file

Tags: hadoop, hive, null, hiveql

I'm trying to download the results of Hive queries using 'Write to directory' feature of Hive. For some columns my query is returning `NULL` values but in the generated file I can see this being replaced by `\N`.
Is this the expected behavior of Hive? I have to upload the generated files to Bigquery tables. Is there any way to generate `NULL` for null values instead of `\N` because after receiving `\N` in the file I'll have to do the intermediate processing( replacing `\N` with `NULL` or empty string).
Please suggest.

Answer (score 5):

You can define how `NULL` will be serialized using `NULL DEFINED AS`:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY "/path/to/your/dir" 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," NULL DEFINED AS '' 
select ...
```

Comment: When i am trying to use NULL DEFINED AS '' the i am getting error: AILED: ParseException line 1:128 cannot recognize input near 'ESCAPED' 'BY' '"\\"' in statement.  Following statement i am using. 
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY "/home/jainro/hdfs_result/" ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","  NULL DEFINED AS ""  ESCAPED BY "\\" Select UNIT,  from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(GCRS_LAST_REFRESH_DT,"yyyy-MM-dd HH24:mm:ss"))  from test_env.test_table limit 10;

Comment: @Rohit Try in exactly the same order https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Writingdataintothefilesystemfromqueries

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me after correcting the sequence of clauses as shown in below code snippet.

```sql
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY <location>
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
NULL DEFINED AS ''
STORED AS TEXTFILE
<SELECT QUERY>
```